# Resized UIWebView returns to original size when scrolling inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a UIScrollView with certain details, labels, etc,on top, and a UIWebView with HTML content at the bottom. (I know I shouldn't put a UIWebView inside of a UIScrollView, but I need all the content to be scrollable, not just the webview).

My steps are:

1) I set the `UIWebView scrollEnabled=NO`, and calculate the UIWebView content size and update Its frame: (in `webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`)

```
CGRect WebViewFrame = webView.frame;
WebViewFrame.size.height = 1;
webView.frame = WebViewFrame;
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
WebViewFrame.size = fittingSize;
webView.frame = WebViewFrame;
```

2) I calculate all the UIScrollView's content and update it's `contentSize`:

```
CGFloat contentHeight = 0;
contentHeight += mainInfoView.frame.size.height;
contentHeight += .......
contentHeight += webView.frame.size.height;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, contentHeight)];
```

At first this appears to work perfectly, the UIWebView gets resized to the correct size, and the UIScrollView's contentSize seems to expand as expected.

**THE PROBLEM** is when I scroll or move the scroll view, the UIWebView instantly returns to its original size, and I think the UIScrollView contentSize also changes. 
And I have no idea why.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you are using `autolayout`

Disable the autolayout property.

Reason why its happening : Autolayout will update the views to their original position using current constraints.

Comment: Wow, you are completely right! I didn't knew Autolayout updated the views positions like that.
Thank you so much, for the information and the help! :)

Comment: did it help you ? accepting and upvoting the answer would be so cool.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I'm a new user and I don't have enough reputation to vote up yet, I'm sorry. Will do as soon I'm able!

Comment: can anyone let me know how to disable autolayout

Comment: To disable `autolayout` set 
    `yourOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`